# IE8 doesn't load background-image

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

IE8 won’t display background images on a div.

My HTML:

```
<section class="section-divider textdivider divider1">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Info About The Foundation</h1>
                <hr>
                <p>Microfestival stable energy fields natural homebirth sarong watsu, aura discovering valuable truths. Nature equinox forest, feline acupuncture salvia. Didgeridoo prius what the planet really needs, divine feminine compostable toilet change agent closing circle feeling deep gratitude sustainable rain dance prayerformance. Beltane perineum cuddle party, bioneers radiant.</p>
                <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-success">More About The Foundation</a>
            </div>
</section>
```

My CSS:

```
.divider1 {
    background-image: url('../images/bg/divider1.jpg')
}
```

In IE8 the image doesn't even load. It just displays the text without any styles being used at all. Is it because IE8 cannot read images for a div? I've looked around and didn't see any indication that IE8 cannot do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, `<section>` is a new HTML5 element, meaning IE8 does not automatically recognize it. Have you A) added an html5shiv and B) set the display property in CSS?

### HTML5Shiv

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script>document.createElement("section");</script>
<![endif]-->
```

### CSS

```
section { display:block; }
```

90% of the time, the reason my new projects won't work on IE8 is because I forgot to add these two.

Comment: yeah that worked I had a shiv just didn't add the css section thanks.

Comment: yw. This one gets me every time. In SublimeText I've started adding the shiv and css to my boilerplate because I'd certainly forget it.